# Javascript - preloaded image is rendered late (only for the first time)

Tags: javascript, image, preload, drawimage

I use this code to preload an image:

```
var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
image.src = "someImage.png";

function loadHandler()
{
  // the programme continues
}
```

Lets say the image refers to a certain button that occurs in the middle of a game.

The problem is that the code waits for a few seconds when the image should be rendered for the first time (using drawImage function). All the other usage (means the image should be shown another time) are instant.

The image is a sprite sheet, size about 3 MB. Everything on a local computer.

Comment: That's exactly what your code should do. What did you expect, what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I put it wrong. The loadHandler function is at the beginning of the code where is meant to stop until the image is loaded. That´s OK. But after the image is loaded and the code proceeds it then stops in the middle of the game when the image should be draw for the first time. However, the second draw and all the other are done without any hesitation.

Comment: No need to be sorry. It's just not clear what you expect to happen. When do you run that preload code?

Comment: To solve this issue I draw part of the image at the beginning of the code (while initializating variables etc) - only a small part of the image, but it helps. So the first drawing - and the few seconds waiting - is done at the beginning of the game so it looks like the set up of the game just took a little more time. But this is not a systematic solution :(

Comment: Sounds like the preloading is not working. Are you sure the preloaded image source and the one that is called later are absolutely the same (same domain, no query strings)? Open the network tab in your Dev Tools, and see if they're identical.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly your issue, it's not about loading but more about rendering the sprite (which is quite big).

It might help to insert it into the `document` (wherever you want) and then wait for it to load before doing anything else.

You can hide it with the help of `opacity`, `visibility`, etc. properties (any choice should do the trick).

If your target browsers are supporting it, you could also use instead [link prefetching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching).